# Is begging a laid-off employee to stay an offer of employment?

Tags: united-states, arizona, unemployment

About a month ago, I asked [a question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/168434/what-should-i-do-if-hr-doesnt-know-about-a-planned-layoff) over on Workplace. TL;DR: I was informally told I was being laid off, but when I asked HR about rights and benefits, they were totally unaware of any layoff.

Looks like I was right to be suspicious, because there was no layoff. Now my immediate supervisor is begging me to "extend" my employment. I've already given them an extra two weeks. (I guess I'll find out on the 19th whether I'm actually being paid...) Now I'm being asked for another "extension."

I've already made financial and personal decisions with the understanding that I'm being laid off. My supervisor does not have unilateral authority to make job offers. **Does being asked to "extend" after being "laid off" constitute a job offer for purposes of claiming unemployment? In other words, if I refuse to be jerked around like this, have I "quit"?**

Comment: It's not quite clear - are you employed or unemployed right now?

Comment: @gnasher729 I've informally agreed to work two more days. This is two weeks past when I was informally told I would be laid off. I've informally been asked if I would consider working longer -- framed exactly like that, not that an offer is on the table.

Answer (score 4):

If you have already claimed unemployment, this might be considered a job offer. If you have not yet field a claim, then it doesn't matter, only offers after a claim is field affect unemployment benefits to the best of my understanding.

You could ask for a job offer in writing. If one is not provided, that is pretty good evidence that there never was an offer. If one is provided, you will have a clearer notice of the offered terms and duration, and that the offer is authorized, and can better judge what to do.